# Existence of real valued function with given partial derivatives.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $F_{1},F_{2}:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the functions $$F_{1}(x,y)=\frac{-y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}, F_{2}(x,y)=\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}}
.$$

How to prove that there is no function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=F_{1}$  and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=F_{2}$.

But there are function $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $D$ is the open disc of radius $1$ centred at $(2,0)$ which satisfies   $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=F_{1}$  and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=F_{2}$. I have no idea about this concept. I think it is related to line integral. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\;f(x,y)\;$ be such a function, then

$$f(x,y)=\int\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx=\int\frac{-y\,dx}{x^2+y^2}=-\int\frac{\frac1ydx}{1+\left(\frac xy\right)^2}=-\arctan\frac xy+K(y)$$

with $\;K(y)\;$ a function of $\;y\;$ *constant wrt* $\;x\;$ . Now compare partial derivatives wrt $\;y\;$:

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\stackrel{\text{given}}=\color{red}{\frac x{x^2+y^2}}\stackrel{\text{by the above}}=\frac x{y^2}\frac1{1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}}+K'(y)=\color{red}{\frac x{x^2+y^2}+K'(y)}\implies$$

$$K'(y)=0\implies K(y)=C=\text{ constant}$$

and thus, finally,

$$f(x,y)=-\arctan\frac xy+C$$

Can you see now how anything containing the origin won't work?

Answer (score 0):

For your first question: if $f$ was such a function define the $2\pi$-periodic function $g(t)=f\bigl(\cos(t),\sin(t)\bigr)$ on $\mathbb R$. Then verify that $g'(t)=1$ in contradiction to the periodicity of $g$.

Comment: How is it periodical?

Comment: Because the arguments of $f$ are $2\pi$-periodic.  Verify for example that $g(t)=g(t+2\pi)$ ...